# Group numbers by increasing increments of 5 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column values as below:

```
x1  x2 
0   20
1   20
2   20
3   20
4   20
5   20
6   20
7   20
8   20
9   20
10  20
```

I want to group the elements in x1 within a size of 5 like this in group_x1. x2 is not relevant in this case.

```
x1  x2 group_x1
0   20  0
1   20  0
2   20  0
3   20  0
4   20  0
5   20  1
6   20  1
7   20  1
8   20  1
9   20  1
10  20  1
```

so values between 0 to 4 in numbers are mapped to 0
and values from 5 to 9 is mapped to 1.

I tried pq.cut and groupby functions but it doesnt work.need it for values from 0 to 25,000

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the desired output - In this case, you want a series with index values from `group_x1` and the series values are lists of matching values from `x1`?
For example: `0: [0,1,2,3,4]` and `1: [5,6,7,8,9]`

Comment: yes@Elisha , this will be applied on a list with numbers ranging from 0 to 25000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['group_x1'] = df['x1'] // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df['group_x1']=np.arange(len(df))//5
df
Out[170]: 
    x1  x2  group_x1
0    0  20         0
1    1  20         0
2    2  20         0
3    3  20         0
4    4  20         0
5    5  20         1
6    6  20         1
7    7  20         1
8    8  20         1
9    9  20         1
10  10  20         2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `groupby` and `apply` on the relevant columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0], [1], [5], [6]], columns=['x1'])
df['x1_group'] = (df['x1'] / 5).astype(int)
groups = df.groupby('x1_group')['x1'].apply(list)
```

Which yields:

```
x1_group
0    [0, 1]
1    [5, 6]
```

In this case, the groups key is `group_x1` and for each group only `x1` values are processed using `list` by the `apply` method.